# Recover Deleted Voice Memo

Tags: iphone, voice-memo, file-recovery

I was trimming a just recorded Voice Memo and accidentally kept the part I wanted to delete instead.

Is there any way to get the original file back?

Answer (score 1):

Once it's deleted, it's gone.  You can check your last iCloud backup.  If it was after the recording but before the delete, you might be able to get it back.

There's about a dozen iPhone recovery-type tools on the net.  A little searching will identify who they are and how to get them (I won't list them here because I don't have experience with them).  They *claim* to be able to recover voice memo's but YMMV.